# How to Deploy Angular 6 to Azure Web App - You do not have permissions

Tags: angular, azure

I have created a clean Angular 6 App. I add following web.config to the src folder:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I added  "src/web.config" in the assets section in the angular.json file. I have updated the node version on the web app to 10.6.

When I deploy the application and navigato to site I get following:You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

I followed following sample:
https://itnext.io/easy-way-to-deploy-a-angular-5-application-to-azure-web-app-using-vsts-pipelines-4a288b9deae1

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It took me entirely too long to figure this out.  I hope it helps.

- In your app service, Click "Application Settings".  Scroll to the bottom.  You will see "Virtual applications and directories".  Your virtual path should be "/" and physical path should be "site/wwwroot/"  Change your Physical path to "site/wwwroot/'appname'"  "appname" should be whatever the name of your application is.  Or it should be whatever folder is inside of your "dist".

Comment: Also, I did not have to add a web.config.  That simple change fixed it for me.

Comment: this change fixed the issue for me as well

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect you to get this error message but in the web.config I miss the part where you define the MimeMap for json files. Please try this web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
     </staticContent>

      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See also: [Web.config for hosting an Angular application on Azure Web App](https://about-azure.com/2018/02/06/web-config-for-hosting-an-angular-application-on-azure-web-app/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried, but same. I wonder if it can be something with the node version on the App Service.

Comment: I got a little more clever. I just deployed the complete project and not just the content of the dist folder. But now I have following problem. If you go to https://angtest5.azurewebsites.net/ it dosent load anything. However https://angtest5.azurewebsites.net/index.html. The web server i a node server will it read the web.con file at all, if it is not a IIS host? Also do you know how to tell the server to load the index.html by default?