# i have a file json file in assets folder in angular but after uploading in server getting error 404 not found

Tags: angular, ftp, azure-web-app-service, assets

error = " https://my.azurewebsites.net/assets/data/plaindata.json 404 (Not Found)", i have done the ng build --prod and copied all files of the dist folder in the wwwroot. in the local its working fine but in azurewebsites.net its not working saying not found.

folder structure of application

src -> assets -> data -> plaindata.json
folder structure of wwwroot folder in server
wwwroot -> assets -> data -> plaindata.json
im able to see the file in the ftp but its throwing error in angular

Answer (score 0):

In order for your angular app to load properly with plaindata.json after deploying it from Dist folder, Make sure the virtual path is set correctly to your app.

You can also set the json file path in the virtual path for it to load.

[image]

In addition to this check if the Default Documents are set like below:-

[image]

Also, Check the Log Stream to find the specific error on why your page is not loading after deployment:-

**Enable App service Logs like below:-**

[image]

**Check the Logs in Log Stream:-**

The log stream logs will give you an insight on what is the error due to the json file.

[image]

[image]

Refer this [Medium blog](https://henriquesd.medium.com/deploying-a-net-5-web-api-and-a-sql-database-in-azure-24e5cae7d6fe) and this [SO thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327444/how-to-deploy-angular-6-to-azure-web-app-you-do-not-have-permissions) and [SO thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984731/angular-app-deploy-to-azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view) answer to resolve your issue.